# LMMS Doesn't Play Audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, lmms

That's pretty much it. LMMS doesn't make any sounds. Which makes the program very difficult to use.

I don't understand why. Literally every other program on my computer plays sounds fine. Including Firefox, Chrome, Spotify, Audacity (with ALSA).

I have a very normal setup. Haven't mucked around with any settings. LMMS was installed with `apt-get install lmms`.

Ubuntu 16.10, LMMS 1.1.3. Let me know if you want other info.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the jack connection app to get audio to work, ALSA wouldn't do anything. I'm on Mint 17.3(ubuntu 14)

```
$ sudo apt-get install qjackctl
```

then run with

```
$ qjackctl
```

it seemed to wire up the connection automatically. Try restarting LMMS after you start jack if you get problems.
[image]

Comment: Jack seems to hog the audio control and youtube won't work while its running, kind of annoying

Comment: I agree here. Jack's what's going to be important for lmms. You'll need it. Youtube's probably going to be playing through ALSA so I expect you can connect the ALSA output ports on the left in your image to the system on the right and you should be able to hear sound on Youtube with Jack (via ALSA).

Comment: @nickfox - JACK will take over audio processing by design, necessary for low latency audio required by LMMS. Audio normally playing in Pulseaudio (web browser etc) can be connected to JACK with Pulseaudio Jack Sink

Answer (score 0):

The default settings of LMMS did not work on my Ubuntu 16.04 either, but I changed its audio API to **SDL (Simple Direct Media Layer)** and it worked fine.

[image: Setup LMMS]